# Do browsers still swallow unhandled rejected promises silently? What about Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

There is a lot of advice out there that advises you to ensure that you don't let any rejected promises go unhandled. If you don't, the advices cautions, the errors will never be noticed, and will be completely swallowed. Nothing will be printed to the console.

This advice seems to be out-of-date. Modern browsers and modern versions of Node do seem to print warnings when rejected promises are unhandled. Take this code:

```
async function thisIsGoingToFail() {
  await Promise.reject();
  console.log('this should not print, as the line above should error');
}

async function main() {
  await thisIsGoingToFail();
}

main();
```

If you run this in Node, you will get:

```
(node:20760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:20760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:20760) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The standard advice is that the last line in the source code should look like this instead, to avoid swallowed errors:

```
main().catch(err => { console.err(err) });
```

But it doesn't look like that like was needed. So here are my questions:

- Is it true that modern browsers and modern Node will always show a warning for unhandled rejected promises? What version numbers of the implementations support this?

  - (Note that a browser doesn't have to support the event `unhandledrejection` in order to print a warning when a promise is not handled.)
- Do we need to make sure to have top-level `catch` functions as you would often get advised to do, or is it just as useful to let the implementation show a warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most modern implementations do print warnings to the console when rejected promises are unhandled, but not all:

- ✓ **Node.js** Since version 6.6.0 (see [changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V6.md#2016-09-14-version-660-current-fishrock123)):

  > promises: Unhandled rejections now emit a process warning after the first tick. (Benjamin Gruenbaum) [#8223](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/8223)

  In future versions, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
- ✓ **Firefox** does show a warning, but I am unable to find which was the first version that does this. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Examples#The_case_of_unhandled_rejections) say this:

  > We adopt the following strategy: if a promise is rejected at the time of its garbage-collection **and** if the promise is at the end of a promise chain (i.e. thatPromise.then has never been called), then we print a warning.
  >
  > > **Note:** This warning is generated some time after the error occurred, and may provide less information about the error location. It generally indicates the need to insert a proper error handler. When a proper rejection handler is used, it effectively replaces this delayed reporting.
- ✓ **Chrome** does show a warning, but again I can't find documentation indicating which is the first version to do this. Chrome >= 49 goes a step further, and has support for the [`unhandledrejection` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection), which lets you add a custom event handler to deal with all unhandled rejected promises.
- ✓ **Safari** also shows a warning, and since version >= 11, also supports the `unhandledrejection` event.
- ✗ **Edge** does not seem to support it yet, based on this [open GitHub issue in Microsoft/ChakraCore](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/2530).

So it looks like most modern browsers (except Edge) do show warnings for unhandled rejected, but there isn't clear documentation guaranteeing that a warning will be shown, or that it will be shown promptly. Handling the `unhandledrejection` event seems like a good idea for the browsers that support it.

---

**tldr;** As of writing, it seems like the best practise is to still have top-level rejected promise handlers with `catch` (to avoid swallowed errors in Edge and terminated processes in Node). For Chrome and Safari, it might be useful to take advantage of `unhandledrejected` event.

Comment: The `unhandledRejection` event and its listener is not really ment to be lazy and ignore those error or handle them at that place. The prefered choice is still to handle the exception at the place where the chain ends (at the place where you neither return it or pass it further).

Comment: @t.niese Why is that the preferred choice? Having failures being silently ignored is a big problem, having warnings printed to the console is not a big problem, and is no worse then forgetting a `try {} catch {}` for synchronous code.

Comment: If you only log those rejection without killing the application then your application might - depending on the error - become unresponsive over time. So a restart and a fast fix could be a better solution then a application that got stuck. The problem with the `unhandledrejected` is you get those errors at a place where you cannot really resolve the problem. E.g. closing/releasing a connection to a database, closing a socket and allowing to reopen it, ... . You should see `unhandledRejection` as a way to get into an emergency mode, in case you didn't properly catch the exception.

Comment: Edge is now based on Chromium, and therefore supports this.